# Why is my android activity performing so slow?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, onclicklistener

From the second you click on the notification activity button the program immediately starts acting slow. This screen for some reason takes minutes to scroll down in a very glitchy and drawn out manner. What can I do to speed up and smooth out my notification activity screen?

NotificationActivity:

```
public class NotificationActivity extends BaseActivity {
public static final String TAG = LoginActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private NotificationAdapter notificationAdapter;
private HeaderLayout headerLayout;
private FooterLayout footerLayout;
private SimpleGestureFilter detector;
private ListView mNotificationLv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_notification);
    mNotificationLv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.notification_lv);
    mNotificationLv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.notification_lv);

    notificationAdapter = new NotificationAdapter(this);
    notificationAdapter.setList(AtlasApplication.lstNotificationModels);
    mNotificationLv.setAdapter(notificationAdapter);

    // Detect touched area
    detector = new SimpleGestureFilter(this,this);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    List<NotificationModel> userModelList = AtlasApplication.lstNotificationModels;
    notificationAdapter = new NotificationAdapter(this);
    notificationAdapter.setList(userModelList);
    mNotificationLv.setAdapter(notificationAdapter);
}
}
```

NotificationAdapter:

```
public class NotificationAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

private List<NotificationModel> lstNotificationModels;
private SQLiteAdapter sqLiteAdapter;
private Context context;
public NotificationAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context; sqLiteAdapter=new SQLiteAdapter(context, this, new Dialog(context));
}

public void setList(List<NotificationModel> genres) {
    this.lstNotificationModels = genres;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView mNotifiactionTypeTv, mNotifiactionTextTv, mNotifiactionTimeTv;
    LinearLayout rowNotificationLl;
}

public void setRead(int i){
    sqLiteAdapter.updateNotificationStatus(i, "read");
    lstNotificationModels.get(i).setmNotificationStatus("read");
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_notification, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.rowNotificationLl = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_notification_ll);
        holder.mNotifiactionTextTv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.notification_text_tv);
        holder.mNotifiactionTimeTv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.notification_time_tv);
        holder.mNotifiactionTypeTv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.notification_type_atv);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    final NotificationModel notificationModel = lstNotificationModels.get(position);
    final String newFullText = sqLiteAdapter.getFullText(notificationModel.getmLawId());

    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date currentDate = new Date();
    Date notificationDate = new Date();
    String timeElapsed = "moments ago.";
    try {
        notificationDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(notificationModel.getmNotificationTime().trim());
    } catch(ParseException e){

    }
    long milliElapsed = currentDate.getTime() - notificationDate.getTime() + 14400000;
    if(milliElapsed>=60000){
        long minutesElapsed = milliElapsed/60000;
        timeElapsed = minutesElapsed + " minutes ago.";
        if(minutesElapsed>=60){
            long hoursElapsed = minutesElapsed/60;
            timeElapsed = hoursElapsed + " hours ago.";
            if(hoursElapsed>=24){
                long daysElapsed = hoursElapsed/60;
                timeElapsed = daysElapsed + " days ago.";
                if(daysElapsed>=7){
                    long weeksElapsed = daysElapsed/7;
                    timeElapsed = hoursElapsed + " weeks ago.";
                    if(weeksElapsed>=4){
                        long monthsElapsed = weeksElapsed/4;
                        timeElapsed = monthsElapsed + " months ago.";
                        if(daysElapsed>=365){
                            long yearsElapsed = daysElapsed/365;
                            timeElapsed = yearsElapsed + " years ago.";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    holder.mNotifiactionTextTv.setText(Html.fromHtml(notificationModel.getmNotificationText().trim()));
    holder.mNotifiactionTimeTv.setText(timeElapsed);
    if (notificationModel.getmNotificationStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("unread")) {
        convertView.findViewById(R.id.unread_vw).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.rowNotificationLl.setBackgroundResource(R.color.black);
    }
    else {
        convertView.findViewById(R.id.unread_vw).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.rowNotificationLl.setBackgroundResource(R.color.grad_light);
    }

    switch (notificationModel.getmNotificationType().toLowerCase()){
        case "traffic":
            holder.mNotifiactionTypeTv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.traffic_noti_bg);
            holder.mNotifiactionTypeTv.setText("f");

            holder.mNotifiactionTypeTv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    try {
                        AtlasApplication.MenuTitle = Constants.CAT_TRAFFIC;
                        AtlasApplication.sCategoryModel = AtlasApplication.lstCategoryModels.get(0);
                        setRead(notificationModel.getmNotificaticationId());
                        view.getContext().startActivity(SubMenuActivity.getIntent(view.getContext()));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        view.getContext().startActivity(SubMenuActivity.getIntent(view.getContext()));
                    }
                }

            });

            holder.mNotifiactionTextTv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    try {
                        AtlasApplication.MenuTitle = Constants.CAT_TRAFFIC;
                        AtlasApplication.sCategoryModel = AtlasApplication.lstCategoryModels.get(0);
                        setRead(notificationModel.getmNotificaticationId());
                        view.getContext().startActivity(SubMenuActivity.getIntent(view.getContext()));
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                        view.getContext().startActivity(SubMenuActivity.getIntent(view.getContext()));
                    }
                }

            });

            break;
        case "law enforcement":
            holder.mNotifiactionTypeTv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.enforcement_noti_bg);
            holder.mNotifiactionTypeTv.setText("c");
            holder.mNotifiactionTypeTv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    try {
                        AtlasApplication.MenuTitle = Constants.CAT_ENFORCEMENT;
                        AtlasApplication.sCategoryModel = AtlasApplication.lstCategoryModels.get(1);
                        setRead(notificationModel.getmNotificaticationId());
                        view.getContext().startActivity(SubMenuActivity.getIntent(view.getContext()));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        view.getContext().startActivity(SubMenuActivity.getIntent(view.getContext()));
                    }
                }
            });

            holder.mNotifiactionTextTv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    try {
                        AtlasApplication.MenuTitle = Constants.CAT_ENFORCEMENT;
                        AtlasApplication.sCategoryModel = AtlasApplication.lstCategoryModels.get(1);
                        setRead(notificationModel.getmNotificaticationId());
                        view.getContext().startActivity(SubMenuActivity.getIntent(view.getContext()));
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                        view.getContext().startActivity(SubMenuActivity.getIntent(view.getContext()));
                    }
                }

            });

            break;
        case "alcohol":
            holder.mNotifiactionTypeTv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.alcohal_noti_bg);
            holder.mNotifiactionTypeTv.setText("a");
            holder.mNotifiactionTypeTv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    try {
                        AtlasApplication.MenuTitle = Constants.CAT_ALCOHOL;
                        AtlasApplication.sCategoryModel = AtlasApplication.lstCategoryModels.get(2);
                        setRead(notificationModel.getmNotificaticationId());
                        view.getContext().startActivity(SubMenuActivity.getIntent(view.getContext()));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        view.getContext().startActivity(SubMenuActivity.getIntent(view.getContext()));
                    }
                }
            });

            holder.mNotifiactionTextTv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    try {
                        AtlasApplication.MenuTitle = Constants.CAT_ALCOHOL;
                        AtlasApplication.sCategoryModel = AtlasApplication.lstCategoryModels.get(2);
                        setRead(notificationModel.getmNotificaticationId());
                        view.getContext().startActivity(SubMenuActivity.getIntent(view.getContext()));
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                        view.getContext().startActivity(SubMenuActivity.getIntent(view.getContext()));
                    }
                }

            });

            break;
        case "taxes":
            holder.mNotifiactionTypeTv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.taxes_noti_bg);
            holder.mNotifiactionTypeTv.setText("e");
            holder.mNotifiactionTypeTv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    try {
                        AtlasApplication.MenuTitle = Constants.CAT_TAXES;
                        AtlasApplication.sCategoryModel = AtlasApplication.lstCategoryModels.get(3);
                        setRead(notificationModel.getmNotificaticationId());
                        view.getContext().startActivity(SubMenuActivity.getIntent(view.getContext()));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        view.getContext().startActivity(SubMenuActivity.getIntent(view.getContext()));
                    }
                }
            });

            holder.mNotifiactionTextTv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    try {
                        AtlasApplication.MenuTitle = Constants.CAT_TAXES;
                        AtlasApplication.sCategoryModel = AtlasApplication.lstCategoryModels.get(3);
                        setRead(notificationModel.getmNotificaticationId());
                        view.getContext().startActivity(SubMenuActivity.getIntent(view.getContext()));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        view.getContext().startActivity(SubMenuActivity.getIntent(view.getContext()));
                    }
                }
            });

            break;
        case "guns":
            holder.mNotifiactionTypeTv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.guns_noti_bg);
            holder.mNotifiactionTypeTv.setText("b");
            holder.mNotifiactionTypeTv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    try {
                        AtlasApplication.MenuTitle = Constants.CAT_GUNS;
                        AtlasApplication.sCategoryModel = AtlasApplication.lstCategoryModels.get(4);
                        setRead(notificationModel.getmNotificaticationId());
                        AtlasApplication.lstLawsForLocation.get(1).setSelected(true);
                        view.getContext().startActivity(SubMenuActivity.getIntent(view.getContext()));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        view.getContext().startActivity(SubMenuActivity.getIntent(view.getContext()));
                    }
                }
            });

            holder.mNotifiactionTextTv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    try {
                        AtlasApplication.MenuTitle = Constants.CAT_GUNS;
                        AtlasApplication.sCategoryModel = AtlasApplication.lstCategoryModels.get(4);
                        setRead(notificationModel.getmNotificaticationId());
                        view.getContext().startActivity(SubMenuActivity.getIntent(view.getContext()));
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                        view.getContext().startActivity(SubMenuActivity.getIntent(view.getContext()));
                    }
                }
            });

            break;
        case "marijuana":
            holder.mNotifiactionTypeTv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.marijuana_noti_bg);
            holder.mNotifiactionTypeTv.setText("d");
            holder.mNotifiactionTypeTv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    try {
                        AtlasApplication.MenuTitle = Constants.CAT_MARIJUANA;
                        AtlasApplication.sCategoryModel = AtlasApplication.lstCategoryModels.get(5);
                        setRead(notificationModel.getmNotificaticationId());

                        view.getContext().startActivity(SubMenuActivity.getIntent(view.getContext()));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        view.getContext().startActivity(SubMenuActivity.getIntent(view.getContext()));
                    }
                }
            });

            holder.mNotifiactionTextTv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    try {

                        AtlasApplication.MenuTitle = Constants.CAT_MARIJUANA;
                        AtlasApplication.sCategoryModel = AtlasApplication.lstCategoryModels.get(5);
                        setRead(notificationModel.getmNotificaticationId());
                        AtlasApplication.lstLawsForLocation.get(1).setSelected(true);
                        view.getContext().startActivity(SubMenuActivity.getIntent(view.getContext()));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        view.getContext().startActivity(SubMenuActivity.getIntent(view.getContext()));
                    }
                }
            });

            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    FontLoader.setAtlasFont(holder.mNotifiactionTypeTv);
    FontLoader.setRalewayRegularFont(holder.mNotifiactionTextTv, holder.mNotifiactionTimeTv);

    holder.rowNotificationLl.setId(position);
    holder.rowNotificationLl.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
}
```

SQLiteAdapter:

```
public class SQLiteAdapter {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

   private static String DB_PATH;//= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + context.getPackageName() + "/";
    private SQLiteDatabase mSqLiteDatabase;
    private Context mContext;
    private Dialog mDialog;
    private SQLiteDbQueryListener sqLiteDbQueryListener;
    private ExceptionHandler exceptionHandler;

    public SQLiteAdapter(Context c, SQLiteDbQueryListener listener, Dialog dialog) {
        mContext = c;
        sqLiteDbQueryListener = listener;
        exceptionHandler = new ExceptionHandler(mContext, "SQLiteAdapter");
        mDialog = dialog;
        DB_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + mContext.getPackageName() + "/";
        //call it so db get copied from assets to sdcard
        //call it so db get copied from assets to sdcard
        openToRead();
        close();
    }

public void updateLaw(int lawID, String newSummary, String newFullText){

    int tagID = getTagID(lawID);
    String tagName = getTagName(tagID);
    int categoryID = getCategoryID(tagID);
    String categoryName = getCategoryName(categoryID);
    String location;
        location = getLocationName(getLocationID(lawID));
        if (location.toLowerCase().equals(AtlasApplication.sHometownSelected.getLocationName().toLowerCase())) {
            location = "your current state";
        } else if (location.toLowerCase().equals(AtlasApplication.sHometownSelected.getLocationName().toLowerCase())) {
            location = "your home state";
        }

    openToWrite();

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(Constants.KEY_SUMMARY, newSummary);
        if(newFullText!=null)
            contentValues.put(Constants.KEY_FULL_TEXT, newFullText);

        mSqLiteDatabase.update(Constants.TABLE_LAW, contentValues, Constants.KEY_LAW_ID + "=" + lawID, null);
    close();
                insertNotification(lawID, categoryName, tagName + " has changed in " + location + ".");

}

public int getCategoryID(int tagID){
    openToRead();
    int categoryID = 0;

    String Query = "SELECT * from " + Constants.TABLE_CATEGORY_TAG;
    Cursor cursor = mSqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(Query, null);
       if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
                    if (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_TAG_ID)) == tagID) {
                            int indexCategoryID = cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_CATEGORY_ID);
                            categoryID = cursor.getInt(indexCategoryID);
                    }
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
        }
    close();
    return categoryID;
}

public String getCategoryName(int categoryID){
    String categoryName = "";
    openToRead();
    String Query = "SELECT * from " + Constants.TABLE_CATEGORY;
    Cursor cursor = mSqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(Query, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
            if (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_CATEGORY_ID)) == categoryID) {
                        int indexCategoryName = cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_CATEGORY_NAME);
                        categoryName = cursor.getString(indexCategoryName);
                }
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
        }
    close();
    return categoryName.toLowerCase();
}

public int getLocationID(int lawID){
    openToRead();
    String Query = "SELECT * from " + Constants.TABLE_LAW_LOCATION;
    Cursor cursor = mSqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(Query, null);
    int locationID = 0;

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
            try {
                if(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_LAW_ID)) == lawID) {
                    int indexTagID = cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_LOCATION_ID);
                    locationID = cursor.getInt(indexTagID);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                exceptionHandler.alert(e, "getLocationID()");
            }
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    close();
    return locationID;
}

public String getLocationName(int locationID){
    openToRead();
    String Query = "SELECT * from " + Constants.TABLE_LOCATION;
    Cursor cursor = mSqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(Query, null);
    String locationName = "";

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
                if(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_LOCATION_ID)) == locationID) {
                    int indexTagID = cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_LOCATION_NAME);
                    locationName = cursor.getString(indexTagID);
                }
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }

    close();
    return locationName;

}

public int getTagID(int lawID){
    openToRead();
    String Query = "SELECT * from " + Constants.TABLE_LAW_TAG;
    Cursor cursor = mSqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(Query, null);
    int tagID = 0;

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
            if(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_LAW_ID)) == lawID) {
                    int indexTagID = cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_TAG_ID);
                    tagID = cursor.getInt(indexTagID);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    close();
    return tagID;
}

public String getTagName(int tagID){
    openToRead();
    String tagName = "";
    String Query = "SELECT * from " + Constants.TABLE_TAG;
    Cursor cursor = mSqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(Query, null);

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
            try {
                if(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_TAG_ID)) == tagID) {
                    int indexTagName = cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_TAG_NAME);
                    tagName = cursor.getString(indexTagName);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                exceptionHandler.alert(e, "getTagName()");
            }
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    close();
    return tagName;
}

public void insertNotification(int lawID, String type, String text){

    openToWrite();
    try {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(Constants.KEY_LAW_ID, lawID);
        contentValues.put(Constants.KEY_NOTIFICATION_TYPE, type);
        contentValues.put(Constants.KEY_NOTIFICATION_TEXT, text);
        contentValues.put(Constants.KEY_NOTIFICATION_STATUS, "unread");

        mSqLiteDatabase.insert(Constants.TABLE_NOTIFICATION, null, contentValues);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        exceptionHandler.alert(e, "insertNotification()");
    }
    close();

}

public void dropNotifications(){
    openToWrite();
    try{
        mSqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS notification");
    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }
    close();
}

public void updateNotificationStatus(int notificationID, String status){
    openToWrite();

    try {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(Constants.KEY_NOTIFICATION_STATUS, status);

        mSqLiteDatabase.update(Constants.TABLE_NOTIFICATION, contentValues, Constants.KEY_NOTIFICATION_ID + "=" + notificationID, null);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        exceptionHandler.alert(e, "updateNotificationStatus()");
    }
    close();
}

public String getNotificationStatus(int notificationID){
    openToRead();
    String Query = "SELECT * FROM " + Constants.TABLE_NOTIFICATION + " WHERE " + Constants.KEY_NOTIFICATION_ID + "=" + notificationID;
    Cursor cursor = mSqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(Query, null);
    String notificationStatus = "";
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
            try {
                if(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_NOTIFICATION_ID)) == notificationID) {
                    int indexNotificationStatus = cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_NOTIFICATION_STATUS);
                    notificationStatus = cursor.getString(indexNotificationStatus);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                exceptionHandler.alert(e, "getNotificationStatus()");
            }
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }

    close();

    return notificationStatus;

}

public int getNotificationId(int lawID, String time){

    openToRead();

    int notificationId = 0;
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + Constants.TABLE_NOTIFICATION +
                " WHERE " + Constants.KEY_NOTIFICATION_TIME + " = " + time;
        Cursor cursor = mSqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
                int indexNotificationID = cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_NOTIFICATION_ID);
                notificationId = cursor.getInt(indexNotificationID);
            }
    }
    close();

    return notificationId;
}

public List<NotificationModel> getNotificationList(){
    List<NotificationModel> lstNotifications = new ArrayList<NotificationModel>();

    openToRead();

    String Query = "SELECT * from " + Constants.TABLE_NOTIFICATION;
    Cursor cursor = mSqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(Query, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
            try {
                int indexNotificationID = cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_NOTIFICATION_ID);
                int indexLawID = cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_LAW_ID);
                int indexNotificationTime = cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_NOTIFICATION_TIME);
                int indexNotificationType = cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_NOTIFICATION_TYPE);
                int indexNotificationText = cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_NOTIFICATION_TEXT);
                int indexNotificationStatus = cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_NOTIFICATION_STATUS);

                int notificationID = cursor.getInt(indexNotificationID);
                int lawID = indexLawID;
                String notificationTime = cursor.getString(indexNotificationTime);
                String notificationType = cursor.getString(indexNotificationType);
                String notificationText = cursor.getString(indexNotificationText);
                String notificationStatus = cursor.getString(indexNotificationStatus);

                lstNotifications.add(new NotificationModel(notificationID, lawID, notificationType, notificationText, notificationTime, notificationStatus));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                exceptionHandler.alert(e, "getNotificationList()");
            }
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    close();
    Collections.reverse(lstNotifications);
    return lstNotifications;
}
```

}

MainActivity:

```
sqLiteAdapter.updateLaw(962, "test", "test");
```

Comment: You can use [systrace](https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/systrace.html) to find the reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue you described is pretty hard to detect in this code but here is a list of notes/best practices you should take into consideration:

- You should ALWAYS do your DB queries on a secondary thread and not on your main thread (Try an AsyncTask).
- you have a SimpleGestureFilter which I can't say what is for or what it does. If you have some ugly logic there, that may affect scrolling.
- You create tons of LayoutInflater variables in your getView() method which is pretty bad. Make it a global variable and initialize it in the Adapter's constructor. Do you have an idea of how many times the getView() method gets called when you scroll? Put a log there and analyse :).
- Definitely not hold an instance to your SQLiteAdapter object in the adapter. Do that in your activity and update your adapter when you need it. The Adapter should always be the representation of your data and not doing having logic and whatever else.
- Not sure what the FontLoader does but if you read a font from the assets every time the getView() is called, you have a huuuge problem. Try to load fonts as few times as possible because that's a heavy operation.
- Never catch general Exceptions. Try to focus on the specific ones.

Comment: A mix between the simple gesture and the threading. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad I could help. Optimize your code and build great apps! Cheers!